# Django DateTimeField has problems with datetime.now

Tags: django, datetime

In Django exists a common pattern to use the following definition in a model:

```
some_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

This is unfortunately problematic since it sets the value of `some_date` to something like: `u'2011-10-18 08:14:30.242000'`.

If you now use a formset to let the user submit/edit additional instances the form will always evaluate to being changed.

The reason is that the the initial datetime value will be `u'2011-10-18 08:14:30.242000'` and the current value from the form widget will be `u'2011-10-18 08:14:30'`. Which is always different.

Unfortunately I can't write something like `"default=currenttime"` and `auto_add` and `auto_now_add` have a different behavior and always sets the field to `editable=False` .

Comment: Somewhere in there you might want to mention what behavior you're after. What should it set the date/time to? How should it work with formsets?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Model's save method like such or replicate this behaviour in forms.Form

```
class Something(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    change_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.pub_date = datetime.datetime.today()
        self.change_date = datetime.datetime.today()
        super(Something, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: hi, I don't see how this could help in my problem above. I don't hate the problem that I don't know what the changed date is. The problem is that the precision of datetime.now is higher then the precision that the html widget can provide, therefore I always get a formset which thinkks contains changed forms.